# SOAP UI connection not working

Tags: rest, user-interface, soap, proxy

I tried with all proxy options and still I get this error when try to create a REST connection to test the data transfer. I even tried to connect from my home and still I get this error. Is it a problem from our side or on the server side where this URL points to?

[image: Error getting response]

Comment: click 'enter image description here' to check screensho of the error